# HangFire recurring task data

Tags: c#, cron, asp.net-mvc-5, recurring, hangfire

I am coding a MVC 5 internet application and am using `HangFire` for recurring tasks.

If I have a Monthly recurring task, how can I get the value of the next execution time?

Here is my code for the recurring task:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("AccountMonthlyActionExtendPaymentSubscription", () => accountService.AccountMonthlyActionExtendPaymentSubscription(), Cron.Monthly);
```

I can retrieve the job data as follows:

```
using (var connection = JobStorage.Current.GetConnection())
{
    var recurringJob = connection.GetJobData("AccountMonthlyActionExtendPaymentSubscription");
}
```

However, I am not sure as to what to do next.

Is it possible to get the next execution time of a recurring task?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're close. I'm not sure if there is a better or otherwise more direct way to get these details, but the way the Hangfire Dashboard does it is to use an extension method (add `using Hangfire.Storage;` to your imports) called `GetRecurringJobs()`:

```
using (var connection = JobStorage.Current.GetConnection())
{
   var recurring = connection.GetRecurringJobs().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == "AccountMonthlyActionExtendPaymentSubscription");

   if (recurring == null)
   {
       // recurring job not found
       Console.WriteLine("Job has not been created yet.");
   }
   else if (!recurring.NextExecution.HasValue)
   {
       // server has not had a chance yet to schedule the job's next execution time, I think.
       Console.WriteLine("Job has not been scheduled yet. Check again later.");
   }
   else
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Job is scheduled to execute at {0}.", recurring.NextExecution);
   }
}
```

There are two catches:

1. It returns all recurring jobs, and you'll need select the appropriate record out of the result
2. When you first create the job, the `NextExecution` time is not available yet (it will be null). I believe the server, once one connects, periodically checks for recurring tasks that need to be scheduled and does so; they do not appear to be immediately scheduled upon creation using `RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(...)` or other such similar methods. If you need to get that `NextExecution` value immediately after creation, I'm not sure what you can do. It will eventually be populated, though.

Comment: I am having 1 mvc application and 1 console application.In console application in my main method i have confifgure Hangfire server and have 1 while loop in order for my console application to keep running.In console app i have 1 method Execute which does background processing.I want to do background processing in console app hence i have configured HF server in console app.But i am not getting how do i enqueue execute method of my console app from mvc