# How to remove all hangfire recurring jobs on startup?

Tags: c#, recurring, hangfire

I am looking at using Hangfire as a job scheduler for recurring jobs.  So configuring them is simple with `AddOrUpdate`, but then how do i delete it? I don't want to pollute my code with `RecurringJob.RemoveIfExists()` when that job has been deleted and then have to remember to delete it later.

Is there a way to get a list of all recurring jobs and delete them when the server starts and so my code will re add them in every time?  If not, if there a better way?

e.g.

Application version 1: Added new Hangfire recurring job *`Do something 1`*

Application version 2: Added new Hangfire recurring jobs *`Do something 2`* and *`Do Something 3`*

Application version 3: Removed Hangfire recurring job *`Do something 2`*

**Problem:** the job will still exist on the server with error "Could not load type..."  and needs to be deleted.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

A bit late on this one but hopefully it will help someone else. I got stuck in the same situation. In the end the answer on [HangFire recurring task data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28447626/hangfire-recurring-task-data) helped me out.

I use the `JobStorage` to loop through all recurring jobs and remove each in turn as below:

```
using (var connection = JobStorage.Current.GetConnection())
{
    foreach (var recurringJob in connection.GetRecurringJobs())
    {
        RecurringJob.RemoveIfExists(recurringJob.Id);
    }
}
```

I am sure there is a nicer way out there but I couldn't find it

Comment: This answer is outdated.

Comment: @ChrisWeber, it works with 1.7.18 which is latest at this time. I only pasted the code, no changes made.

Answer (score 23):

[paul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40277390/how-to-remove-all-hangfire-recurring-jobs-on-startup/41100280#41100280) was helpful but API api seems to have changed.  Using Hangfire 1.6.20 I needed to get the recurring jobs from `StorageConnectionExtensions`

```
using (var connection = JobStorage.Current.GetConnection()) 
{
    foreach (var recurringJob in StorageConnectionExtensions.GetRecurringJobs(connection)) 
    {
        RecurringJob.RemoveIfExists(recurringJob.Id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Need to add a `using Hangfire.Storage` at the top of the file, but yeah, this is what I needed to drop all recurring jobs. Thanks!

Comment: As the StorageConnectionExtensions class is self explanatory, the GetRecurringJobs() method is an extension method of the Connection object, so no need to call it via the static extension class, use connection.GetRecurringJobs() instead.

Comment: Seems it will delete also the history of All recurring Jobs execution. So this approach should not be used for Production.

Answer (score 3):

according to hangfire docs

```
public static void RemoveIfExists(
    string recurringJobId
)
```

with this method, you can pass the job id which you want to delete.

```
RecurringJob.RemoveIfExists("exampleClassName.exampleFunctionName");
```

Comment: `I don't want to pollute my code with RecurringJob.RemoveIfExists() when that job has been deleted and then have to remember to delete it later.`